# zf2 : select columns dont work on tablegateway

Tags: select, model, zend-framework2

I created the method 'fetchAll()' in my model in this way

```
public function fetchAll(){

    $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select( function (Select $select) {

        $select->columns(array('my_alias'=>'my_field'));

    });

    return $resultSet;

}
```

so, i get the results in controller

```
...

$items = $this->getMyTable()->fetchAll();

...
```

and i sendo to my action

```
...

foreach( $items => $item ){ print $item->my_alias; } 

...
```

but '$item->my_alias' is not defined. Without 'columns' method, its work. Whats wrong ?

Comment: show the exact code in the controller, action model and mapper. That will help me and anyone who's viewing to figure this out. It looks pretty straightforward though

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
public function fetchAll(){

    $select = new Select();
    $select->from('table');
    $select->columns(array('my_alias' => 'my_field'));
    $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);
    return $resultSet;
}
```